# Dúvida Semântica html5

Tags: html5, semântica

Qual o certo para barra lateral?

```
<div>
   <aside></aside>
   <aside></aside>
</div>
```

---

```
<aside>
   <section></section>
   <section></section>
</aside>
```

---

```
<section>
   <aside></aside>
   <aside></aside>
</section>
```

E alguém poderia me explicar regras sobre quando usar `<div>` ou `<section>`?

Comment: Da uma olhada no guia de estrutura, ele mostra o que era utilizado no HTML4 e o que esta sendo indicado a utilizar no HTML5 https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_structural_elements

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Sobre `<aside>`:

A especificação da [W3C acerca do aside](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/aside) diz assim:

> *The `<aside>` element represents a section of a page that consists of content that is tangentially related to the content around the aside element, and which could be considered separate from that content.*

Isso quer dizer que deve ser usado para reúnir conteúdo que está "tangencialmente relacionado" com a página. Eu entendo isso como widgets, links a páginas relacionadas e outros links/partes que não tenham diretamente a ver com a página.

Dito isso eu não usaria `<aside>` para uma sidebar senão em casos específicos de referências externas +/- relacionadas coma minha página.

#### Sobre `<section>`:

Olhando o que diz a [especificação para `<section>`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/section):

> *The `<section>` element represents a generic section of a document or application.*

Traduzido livremente: *"Um elemento que representa uma secção genérica do documento"*.

#### Sobre `<div>`:

O elemento `<div>` pode ser usado para qualquer coisa. A W3C diz exatamente isso:

> *The  element has no special meaning at all.*

Por isso usa sempre que precisares de agrupar conteúdo sem significado semântico especial.

---

## O que usar então?

O elemento correto depende do conteúdo que estás a agrupar nessa sidebar.

Assim se tiveres dentro da sidebar:

- links e navegação interna:

  Usa a tag `<nav>`. A W3C diz que a tag `<nav>` deve marcar uma secção com links de navegação.

  > *The `<nav>` element represents a section with navigation links.*
- links para outras página, de conteúdo mais ou menos relacionados:

  Usa a tag `<aside>`.

Answer (score 2):

Em relação ao significado semântico dos elementos, a atual autoridade é a [especificação do HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/), promulgada pelo World Wide Web Consortium.

## O elemento [`<section>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-section-element)

Representa uma seção do documento. Trata-se de um grupo temático de conteúdo, identificado por um título que é representado pelos elementos [`<h1>` a `<h6>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements). A especificação cita exemplos concretos:

- Capítulos
- Seções numeradas de uma tese
- Web site com seções de introdução, notícias e informações de contato
- As páginas individuais em uma interface guias

## O elemento [`<aside>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-aside-element)

Representa uma seção do documento que consiste de conteúdo que pode ser considerado separado, tangencial ao conteúdo em volta do elemento. A especificação fornece como exemplos de uso:

- Citações
- Publicidade
- Grupos de elementos [`nav`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element)
- Análogos às barras laterais do meio impresso

## O elemento [`<div>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element)

Não representa nada em especial; apenas agrupa elementos e atribui a eles semântica comum através dos atributos [`class`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#classes), [`lang`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#attr-lang) e [`title`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#attr-title).

A especificação recomenda que autores usem o elemento `<div>` apenas quando nenhum outro elemento apresentar a semantica apropriada. Isso faz dele o último recurso do desenvolvedor.

## O que usar?

Utilizar o `<aside>` dentro do `<div>` é semanticamente pobre e portanto desencorajado.

Não é absolutamente necessário que um `<aside>` esteja dentro de uma `<section>`, nem que uma `<section>` esteja dentro de um `<aside>`.

O uso correto depende da semântica do seu conteúdo.

- Se o conteúdo da `<section>` está relacionado ao `<aside>`

  Coloque o `<aside>` dentro da `<section>` para deixar clara a relação de parentesco.

  ```
  <section>
    <h1>Título</h1>
    <p>Conteúdo.</p>

    <aside>
      <blockquote>Citação relacionada ao conteúdo.</blockquote>
    </aside>
  </section>
  ```
- Se o conteúdo da `<section>` não está relacionado ao `<aside>`

  Coloque o `<aside>` ao lado da `<section>` para deixar clara a relação de irmandade.

  ```
  <aside>
    <nav>
      <h1>Capítulos</h1>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="capítulo-1">Capítulo 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="capítulo-2">Capítulo 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="capítulo-3">Capítulo 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </aside>

  <section>
    <h1>Capítulo 2</h1>
    <p>Conteúdo do capítulo 2.</p>
  </section>
  ```
- Se o `<aside>` é extenso

  Coloque várias `<section>`s dentro do `<aside>` para deixar claro o delineamento do documento e os limites entre as seções.

  ```
  <aside>
    <h1>Publicidade</h1>

    <section>
      <!-- Primeiro banner -->
    </section>

    <section>
      <!-- Segundo banner -->
    </section>
  </aside>
  ```

Vários exemplos reais de uso podem ser encontrados na própria especificação, nas seções de cada elemento.

---

> E alguém poderia me explicar regras sobre quando usar `<div>` ou `<section>`?

A diferença entre os dois é que o `<section>` representa uma subdivisão do documento HTML5. Ele secciona o documento, dividindo-o em partes. É análago a como um livro é subdividido em capítulos e vários outros elementos pré-textuais e pós-textuais.

O `<div>` simplesmente representa os elementos nele contidos. Não há nenhuma implicação na estrutura semântica do documento.

Imagine uma extensão para navegadores que [delineia as páginas](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#outline) e mostra um sumário para o usuário para facilitar a navegação. Seria mais fácil para o programa analisar a página se [suas seções estiverem claramente identificadas](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#sectioning-content-0). Só é possível criar um sumário para os livros porque os capítulos estão claramente delineados. Se o desenvolvedor usar apenas `<div>`s em sua página, o trabalho do programa fica muito mais difícil, há incerteza em relação a verdadeira estrutura do documento e isso gera a possibilidade de resultados insatisfatórios: sumários inúteis que não levam o usuário a nenhum lugar útil.